# Google Cloud VPC Peering additional routes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I currently have two VPCs

- A (10.10.0.0/16)
- B (10.90.0.0/16)

They are connected trough VPC peering and can contact each other. I have now setup an openvpn server in VPC B, and want the connected clients to be accessible by VPC A. The clients of the openvpn server have IPs in the 10.9.0.0/16 range.

Which route (and how) would I need to add to google cloud to make this possible? I assume I need a VPN Tunnel route, but that list is empty in my google cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

As the tunnel terminates on an instance in the VPC running OpenVPN, I would try followings:

1) A [static route](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#static-route-next-hops) to the client network(10.9.0.0/16) range with OpenVPN server as the next hop (next hop=Openvpn server instance).

2) [IP forwarding](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/265-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding) turned on the instance, running OpenVPN server

3) Tune down the MTU to make sure it's not greater than 1460 bytes on the clients to get this going. Details of this can be found in the GCP "[Gateway MTU vs. system MTU](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/mtu-considerations#gateway_mtu_vs_system_mtu)" and "[Performance considerations](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/mtu-considerations#performance_considerations)". I would also recommend reviewing "[MTU Considerations](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/mtu-considerations#gc-wrapper)" documentation as a whole for more details.